# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Operation Complected successfully

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I'm creating a windows form with multiple panels to display graphics using C#.

```
try
{
    if (myBuffer != null)
        myBuffer.Dispose();
    myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(this.panel1.CreateGraphics(), this.panel1.DisplayRectangle);
}
catch (Win32Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

This is the code am using.

I'm getting this error **System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Operation Complected successfully** while maximizing the window from the minimized state.

Answer (score 1):

The BufferedGraphicsContext class is an implementation detail that should have been made internal.  It isn't resilient enough to mistakes like creating one for an invisible control.  Clearly its exception reporting hasn't been debugged well enough either, not uncommon for code that doesn't get subjected to mistakes often enough.

Clearly you are doing this to double-buffer Panel controls, they are not by default.  Simply create your own control, derived from Panel.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile and drop the new control added to the top of the toolbox onto your form, replacing your existing ones.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class BufferedPanel : Panel {
    public BufferedPanel() {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```